# A form for editing the objects (tags) in a many-to-many relationship? (Django)

Tags: django, forms, list, view, many-to-many

I have a model `Post` and a model `Tag`. Each post can have multiple related tags.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    url = models.CharField()

class Tag(models.Model): 
    post= models.ForeignKey('my_app.Post', 
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='tags')
    tag_text = models.CharField()
```

I want to create a form so as to be able to edit the existing tags of a single post as a string delimited by commas.

I know how to get the tags of a post as a list and turn the list into a string and vice versa, but I'm unsure how to create a new form for that.

Comment: what you want here is to create a form that is not a modelform, but that has the fields of the `post` as well as an extra field for `tags`.  You would validate the other fields normally, and then parse the `tags` field into individual `tag` instances, add them to the post model, and save.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you have defined above a many-to-one relationship between `post` and `tag`.